# Array of percentages which can add up to 100

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have been asked  the following question in an interview and I am still thinking of an efficient way of doing it.

You have an array whose numbers represent percentages of liquids in a barrel.You also have an API with a method: `combine(int x,int y)` which takes two input percentages in the array and combines the liquid from one barrel to another. By using this information you have to find maximum number of barrels that can be possible with 100% liquid.

**Example 1.** Array: 10,15,20,35,55,65

**Ans**:Number of barrels would be 2.
Since `combine(65,35)`---one 100% barrel,
`combine(55,20)`--75% barrel, next `combine(75,15)`--90% next `combine(90,10)`--100%--1 barrel
So total 2 barrels

**Example 2: 99,99,99**

**Ans:** Number of barrels would be 1 here since you do `combine(99,99)`--you get one 100% barrel the rest of the liquid is wasted and you can't combine any other barrel with the third 99% barrel to make it 100

Note:once you pour liquid from one barrel to another you can't use it again 
for ex: `combine(55,15)`--70% barrel. You can use 70% barrel but not 55% and 15% barrels.

Comment: This seems like a variation of bin-packing which is NP-hard but has a lot of good approximation schemes. Do you need to find the optimal answer or can you approximate it?

Comment: The link for bin-packing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem as mentioned by Paulpro. Its recommened reading for you to understand and choose between methods you choose to address the question.

Comment: @Paulpro a variation of? This looks like an exact BPP to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak Notice in example 2 in the OPs question, the answer is `1` (the maximum number of barrels it is possible to fill to >= 100%). Whereas in BPP the answer would be `3` (this minimum number of barrels it takes to not waste any liquid).

Answer (score 2):

You may indeed look at algorithms for bin packing problem. [This student paper](http://acm.zju.edu.cn/dsaa/DS2/P12G05.pdf) indicates four of them. The one with best approximation is Decreasing First Fit algo.

It comes down to quick sort (in place, O(nlogn) time complexity in average and O(n2) in worst case), and then First Fit.

First Fit comes down to scan the bins in order, and place the new item in the first bin that is large enough to hold it. If there is no bin into which current object fits,start a new bin.

To FF in O(nlogn) complexity, use a Max Winner Tree data structure. It has n external nodes (players) and n-1 internal nodes (winner for each match), 
and the winner is the player with max value.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all percentages in the given array are less than 100 (in any case if there were elements at or greater than 100, we could count and remove them immediately), each barrel of 100% cannot be created from less than two array elements, and the number of 100% barrels cannot be more than the sum of the array divided by 100. Therefore, the possibilities to examine are bound by:

```
maxNumBarrels array = min (div (sum array) 100) (div (length array) 2)
```

The following Haskell code provides the function, `divide`, which partitions the array into all variations of n partitions without repetition (that is, both partition order and element order within partitions are ignored). The function, `maxBarrels`, searches backwards, dividing the array first into maxNumBarrels partitions (searching for results with maxNumBarrels elements who's sum is >=100), and then progressively smaller numbers of partitions until an answer is found or a null set is returned.

```
import Data.Map (adjust, fromList, toList)

divide xs n = divide' xs (zip [0..] (replicate n [])) where
  divide' []     result = [result]
  divide' (x:xs) result = do
    index <- indexes
    divide' xs (toList $ adjust (x :) index (fromList result)) where
      populated = map fst . filter (not . null . snd) $ result
      indexes = populated ++ if any (null . snd) result 
                                then [length populated] 
                                else []

maxBarrels xs = allDivided maxNumBarrels where
  maxNumBarrels = min (div (sum xs) 100) (div (length xs) 2)
  allDivided count | count == 0         = []
                   | not (null divided) = divided
                   | otherwise          = allDivided (count - 1)
    where divided = filter ((==count) . length) 
                  . map (filter ((>=100) . sum)) 
                  . map (map snd) 
                  . divide xs $ count
```

OUTPUT:

```
*Main> maxBarrels [10,15,20,35,55,65]
[[[55,20,15,10],[65,35]],[[55,35,10],[65,20,15]]]

*Main> maxBarrels [99,99,99]
[[[99,99,99]]]

*Main> maxBarrels [99,99,99,10,15,25,35,55,65]
[[[15,10,99],[25,99],[35,99],[65,55]] ...(the first of 144 immediate results)...
```